# change time zone in wordpress plugin

Tags: php, html, wordpress, plugins, timezone

i am using a wordpress plugin to show whether the company is open or close.
the plugin name is "Wp Open Hour Widget" below is the url of the plugin.

https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-open-hours/

by default it is taking Europe/London time zone. i need to change it to Texas/Houston time zone. can any one help me.

Comment: Google... https://wordpress.org/support/topic/server-time-different-from-home-time-opening-hours-status-widget

Answer (score 1):

You need to change the WordPress timezone, you can do that at Settings > General > Timezone.

Have a look at this article:
http://help.coschedule.com/hc/en-us/articles/214455448-How-To-Change-Your-WordPress-Timezone

If this doesn't work you can try to place the `date_default_timezone_set` somewhere in your WordPress site. Use an action hook to run the function.

```
add_action('wp_loaded', 'time_zone_function');
function time_zone_function(){
  date_default_timezone_set ( string $timezone_identifier )
}
```

Comment: Top search result for you too. I modified my search with "plugin" and got the one in the comment above

Comment: Just posted the link because of the imagens it's more illustrated

Comment: its not working, i already set time zone requied in my wordpress settings. but still it is showing london time.

Comment: have you tried adding the action to set timezone using the date_default_timezone_set function??

Comment: i have added add_action method but that is also not working.

Comment: Hello Andreas, i tried your specified methods but still didnt get it. can you help me out.